# Попытка вызвать виртуальный метод 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' на ссылку нулевого объекта

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо реализовать справочник для редких животных. При нажатии на фрагмент меню, что бы выходил перечень этих животных и при нажатии на само животное его описание.
Делаю так скажем многоплановое приложение и разметка content_main.xml  у меня уже занята под другие цели. Поэтому я создала разметку content_main_2.xml в нее вложила listView и отдельно сделала разметку для экземпляра списка, далее с помощью адаптера хотела его наполнять.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private ListView list;
private String[] NameArray;
private CustomArrayAdapter adapterlist;
private int categoty_index;
private int position;
private int[] array_image_category = new int []{R.drawable.bla, R.drawable.bla, R.drawable.bla};
private int [] array_image_animal = {R.drawable.bla, R.drawable.bla, R.drawable.bla};
private List<ListItemClass> listItemMain;
private ListItemClass listItem;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    list = findViewById(R.id.listView); //Показывает списки на экране
    listItemMain = new ArrayList<>();
    NameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_array);
    for(int i = 0; i < NameArray.length; i++)//Цикл длится по длине массива(количества в array)
    {
        listItem = new ListItemClass();
        listItem.setNameE(NameArray[i]); //Берем элемент из array и передаем в listitem
        listItem.setImage_id(array_image_category[i]);
        listItemMain.add(listItem);
    }
    adapterlist = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.example_layout, listItemMain,  getLayoutInflater());
    list.setAdapter(adapterlist);

    NavigationView nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0)
            {

            }

        }
    });
```

В логах ошибка:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Я так понимаю это как раз из за разметки, как в таком случае быть?

Comment: ` NameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_array);` тут мне кажется нет переменной, так же покажите на какую строку указывают логи

Comment: Тут ссылка идет на массив с данными в файле Arrays (ссылка category_array).
Ругается он на строку:
" list.setAdapter(adapterlist);", то есть когда я указываю в листе на адаптер, предшествующая строка:
"adapterlist = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.example_layout, listItemMain,  getLayoutInflater());"
example_layout - это разметка с тем как будет выглядеть один элемент из списка, там указан imageView и TextView и все.

Answer (score 0):

Пишете что создали разметку `content_main_2.xml` и в нее вложили `listView`
А сами в метод `setContentView` передаете `activity_main`

Замените

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

на

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_main_2);
```

Comment: Это MainActivity, там изначально предопределенно setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); и поменять не могу, так как там использую эту разметку при вызове других методов. 
Если я ее изменяю, у меня начинает ругаться на поле  drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle), так как использую шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity

Comment: если бы я добавила в content_main свой listView, все бы корректно работало, так уже пробовала, но мне нужно использовать именно content_main2, так как content_main  у меня уже под другие цели настроен.

Comment: Ок. Зайдем с другой стороны. У вас в activity_main есть listView?

Comment: Нет, listView нету, но если я ставлю setContentView(R.layout.content_main2) проблемы не решает. Так как это шаблон студии activity_main и content_main являются образующими и ни там, ни там у меня нет listView и я понимаю, что именно на это и ругается студия. Тут нужно не просто ссылку на разметку менять а использовать что то типа LayoutInflater, но у меня это не особо выходит

Comment: Мне даже сказать вам больше нечего

Comment: Если я ошибаюсь лучше поясните, нежели насмехаться. Данный ресурс как раз для того, что бы те, кто поумнее помогали тем, кто потупее и тем кто только учится.

Comment: В разметке, которую вы передаете в метод `setContentView()` должны быть все `view`, которые вы ищите методом `findViewById` в данной `activity`